# Android Studio: Start activity by clicking widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I'm trying to launch my app when pressing the widget in the home screen in Android Studio using kotlin.

Here's my attempt:

```html
class MyWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray,
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            // Get reference to SharedPreferences
            val widgetData = HomeWidgetPlugin.getData(context)
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.my_widget)

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            val intent = Intent(context, Activity::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.homeWidget, pendingIntent)
            
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks